# How to require mutual TLS in IIS for all requests at specific URL's

Tags: ssl, iis, identityserver4, x509certificate, tls1.2

For Mutual TLS (MTLS), the Identity Server 4 [documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/mtls.html) says Identity Server is configured for MTLS at certain endpoints.

> In IdentityServer, the mutual TLS endpoints are expected to be located beneath the path ~/connect/mtls. This means your web server can be configured to require mutual TLS for all requests at and below that path.

Is there a way to do this in IIS? I've been researching extensively but can't find a way to enable MTLS for specific endpoints.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your config thus far? I think you should be able to use a top level <location path="..."> with a <system.webServer> element below it.

Comment: Hi mackie, I haven't created the configuration yet, but I will be soon and I'm stuck on this particular issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set read/write permissions on the involved nodes in ApplicationHost.config you can set it up in web.config:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <location path="connect/mtls">
        <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert, SslRequireCert" />
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
    ...
</configuration>
```

/Hans

Comment: Thank you for responding. This is also falls along the lines of what Identity Server's Brock Allen said when I asked him the same question [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/3557).

Comment: Dominick Baier has written about setting up MTLS recently:
- Mutual TLS and Proof-of-Possession Access Tokens – Part 1: Setup, https://leastprivilege.com/2020/02/07/mutual-tls-and-proof-of-possession-access-tokens-part-1-setup/

Comment: Oh that's awesome. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In the [readme](https://github.com/blowdart/idunno.Authentication/tree/master/src/idunno.Authentication.Certificate) for the certificate authentication package referenced in the Identity Server [documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/mtls.html), it says:

> **Can I configure my application to require a certificate only on certain paths?**
>
> Not possible, remember the certificate exchange is done that the start of the HTTPS conversation, it's done by the host, not the application. Kestrel, IIS, Azure Web Apps don't have any configuration for this sort of thing.

So I'm thinking it's not possible. But I would certainly appreciate any other feedback as to how to resolve MTLS for Identity Server given certificate authentication isn't possible at specific paths.